# Linux - How to show a text message to a particular user during user login

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a text file in `/opt` which I would like to display to a particular user (e.g.: `/home/sunil`) during login (similar to welcome message).

I know about `/etc/motd` which displays the message for all users during login.

I don't want to use the respective users' `.cshrc`, `.bashrc` or `.profile` etc. because users will be added and deleted constantly.

Is it possible to display text to a particular user during login?

Answer (score 6):

You could create custom message files per user, let's say in `/etc/messages`:

```
/etc/messages/user_a
/etc/messages/user_b
```

And then add the following at the end of `/etc/profile`:

```
if [ -f /etc/messages/${USER} ]; then cat /etc/messages/${USER}; fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, But how the above solution can print /etc/messages/user_a  info to the user_a during his login(as a welcome msg)..

Comment: For the users for which you want a message to appear, you create a text file containing the message as described above. When the user logs in, the `/etc/profile` will get executed, and if a file for that user exists it will be printed out, pretty much the same as a MOTD.

Comment: Thank u,, its good solution,, i understood and implemented your logic,  But in my case the file contents are not being displayed for the user, means /etc/profile log is not being sourced during user login,, well user login has csh as default shell.. is that a problem ?

Comment: @SunilGowda So do it in `/etc/cshrc` or another file that does get sourced instead.

Comment: yes,, i found it,, its "/etc/csh.cshrc"  ,, Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can put a script in `/etc/profile` which will run before the individual user's .profile etc.